# When is a process exactly in waiting state when I/O for a process demanding keyboard input occurs ? I mean the exact little time frame

Tags: c, io, keyboard, cpu, interrupt

Consider the simple c program :

```
int main(){

char str[10];
scanf("%s",str);
printf("The string is %s \n",str);
}
```

According to the book Operating System Concepts a process is in waiting state when it is waiting for some events to occur ( such as an I/O completion or reception of a signal ).
Now as far as I know by the time the process execution reaches the scanf() function the process enters the I/O state (the process stops and is in waiting state). Now it is preempted and another process is executed in the CPU. This system was developed for reasons of efficiency because the CPU shouldn't stay idle when it could execute another process. I totally understand and agree with that. What I don't understand is the exact little time frame within which a process is waiting. Let me explain this more clearly.
Consider the simple program with the scanf() function I just showed here ( let's say it is the process A).
When the process A execution reaches the scanf() function the program expects us to insert something so it stops and we are provided with the window for inserting characters. Is the process A preempted ( CPU is given another process, let's say B) only within the little time interval that extends from when we are asked to insert some value to the exact point in time where the **FIRST** character input is typed on the keyboard ? Does the cpu resume execution of process A as soon as the **FIRST** character is typed or does the cpu resume execution of process A only when all the characters are typed and the **key enter is pressed** to confirm them. Have a look a this picture and tell me which of the two cases are correct or if they are both incorrect. Try also to explain why is that or why isn't like that.
[image]

Comment: Don't post images unless necessary or if necessary, downscale it as much as possible.

Comment: @jtxkopt I would say the image was a helpful visual aid.

Comment: Both cases are possible and also a third case where pressing enter might not be sufficient to recommence program execution. It depends on the stdio buffering mode of the input stream (depending on the default buffering mode for the input stream and usage of `setvbuf`, etc.), and may also depend on how the underlying input device is currently set up (e.g. termios settings of the tty that the input stream is connected to for POSIX systems). On a POSIX system, the tty will typically be in line input mode, and the C runtime library will set stdin to line-buffered mode if it is connected to a tty.

Answer (score 0):

A modern computer would require the enter key be pressed first since it can't return a value only to have you delete it and replace it. However in the first case, process A would have to handle  what to do if the backspace key is hit and when it is done reading from input. This is quite awkward, but it can be done.

```c
char *buffer = /* etc. */;
int index = 0;

while(true) {
    // We pass responsibility to process B to handle waiting for and returning the next key
    // In this case process B is the operating system that handles our IO
    char next = osWaitForKeyPress();

    // Now that we have an input, process A can handle it before waiting again
    if (next == ENTER_KEY) {
        // We finished so add null terminator and exit
        buffer[index] = '\0';
        break;
    } else if (next == BACKSPACE_KEY) {
        // Move index back by 1 to overwrite previous input
        if (index > 0) {
            index = index - 1;
        }
    } else {
        // Add character to buffer and increment index
        buffer[index] = next;
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

However in case 2, we just pass all of the responsibility to process B (aka the OS) and let it handle it for us before process A resumes execution.

```c
// Wait until the OS has a full string of input for us.
// During this time we wait on process B.
char *buffer = fgets(stdin);
```

Hopefully this pseudocode helps clear it up for you.